# Serial number not working in PHP MySql Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I would like to add serial number to my table content via PHP mySql data. I have tried with my code but I am not able to complete the table result. I hope there is no error in my code, but there is an empty field has been shown in my table's serial number data.
Here it is my PHP code..,

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $data_content = '';
    $qry = "SELECT DISTINCT areaName FROM area_Info";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $serial = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $data_content .= "<tr><td><?php echo $serial; ?></td><td><a href=\"areaData.php?area=".$row['areaName']."\">". $row['areaName'] ."</a></td></tr>";
    $serial++;
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

This is my html code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
<table class='area-table'>
    <?php echo $data_content; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are already inside a php string when you try this: `<?php echo $serial; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with php tag inside of string quotes. Please try replace your code

```
$data_content .= "<tr><td><?php echo $serial; ?></td><td><a href=\"areaData.php?area=".$row['areaName']."\">". $row['areaName'] ."</a></td></tr>";
```

with this below code

```
$data_content .= "<tr><td>".$serial."</td><td><a href=\"areaData.php?area=".$row['areaName']."\">". $row['areaName'] ."</a></td></tr>";
```

Also try using mysqli  as mysql is deprecating now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line to:

```
$data_content .= "<tr><td>$serial</td><td><a href='areaData.php?area={$row['areaName']}'>{$row['areaName']}</a></td></tr>";
```

And avoid using the monstrous `mysql_*`.

Comment: You also need a `'` after the open parenthesis of the `include` statement, if it's not a typo!